# Document index time boosting in solr via Apache Nutch

Tags: solr, nutch, solr-boost

I am crawling some websites using apache Nutch. I have to give boost to one website out of all. suppose out of 100 urls, there is a wiki url in seed. I want to give all data from wiki some boot, so that they should be displayed at top. I am using solr 4.10.3.

I recrawl these websites after few days. So I think, index boot via solr will not work, it will be Nutch that should do it. Any idea ?

Comment: Why wouldn't a query time boost work? That way you can tune your boosts individually, and change the boost model depending on what you want to rank higher.

Comment: When I already know that this url should be boosted then I think its better to boot at index time. is'nt it ?